# How to separate just 'and' item from function ? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to single out “and” within the array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialValues) {
      let filteredCommaNames = users
        .filter((user) => selectedUsers?.includes(user.uuid))
        .map((item) => {
          return item.name;
        })

        .join(", ");

      const replaceLastNameWithAnd = filteredCommaNames.replace(
        /,(?=[^,]*$)/,
        " and"
      );
      
      //result is like -> Michael, John, Ivan and Ronald ( in string )
      setNames(replaceLastNameWithAnd);
    }
  }, []);
```

Here i separate all names into single array and just show it

```
   <strong>
    {selectedNames}
   </strong >
```

And this is work good...
Result is **bolded** names example:

**Michael, John, Ivan and Ronald**

What i need ?

To bold only names without and and to be:

**Michael, John, Ivan** and **Ronald**

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [Intl.Listformat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/ListFormat)  (note lack of IE support)

```js
const names = ["Michael", "John", "Ivan", "Ronald"]
const formatter = new Intl.ListFormat('en', {
  style: 'long',
  type: 'conjunction'
});
console.log(formatter.format(names));

console.log(formatter.formatToParts(names))
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {formatter.formatToParts(names).map(({ type, value }, i) => {
        if (type === "element") {
          return <strong>{value}</strong>;
        }
        if (type === "literal") {
          return i === formatter.formatToParts(names).length - 2
            ? removeComma(value)
            : value;
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function removeComma(literalValue) {
  return literalValue.replace(/,/, "");
}
```

[image: Edit nifty-bardeen-klkgq]

Comment: What is new Intl.ListFormat? Some library?

Comment: It is Javascript. There's a link there for you to read.

Comment: Nice but here is one bug. When print name you see -> Michael, John, Ivan, and Ronald. Problem is after Ivan it should not stand comma.  Example  Michael, John, Ivan ( remove this comma , ) and Ronald

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-list-format/issues/31